# Фиксированный размер image в pattern

Tags: html, css, svg

Имеются два "логотипа" на SVG, которые заливаются одним и тем же паттерном:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У них свой размер, свой `viewbox` и скорее всего из-за этого заключается проблема, что `pattern > image` растягивается относительно `viewbox`, вот пример отображения:

```css
/* только для демо */
body {display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; min-height: 100vh; margin: 0;}
svg {box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;}
svg:not(:last-child) {margin-right: 10px;}
```

```html
<svg style="width: 0; height: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; transform: translate(-100%, -100%);">
  <pattern id="pattern-img" x="0" y="0" width="128" height="128" viewBox="0 0 512 512" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <image href="https://i.imgur.com/23k1MXg.jpg"/>
  </pattern>
</svg>

<svg width="30" height="30" viewbox="0 0 30 30">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-img)"/>
</svg>

<svg width="60" height="60" viewbox="0 0 30 30">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-img)"/>
</svg>

<svg width="90" height="90" viewbox="0 0 30 30">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-img)"/>
</svg>
```

Как задать изображению фиксированный размер, который не будет меняться от значений родительского?
Вот такой пример ожидаемого результата, только код отсюда не подойдёт, у SVG, где используется паттерн, меняется `viewbox`.

```css
/* только для демо */
body {display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; min-height: 100vh; margin: 0;}
svg {box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;}
svg:not(:last-child) {margin-right: 10px;}
```

```html
<svg style="width: 0; height: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; transform: translate(-100%, -100%);">
  <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 20 20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <g fill="#333">
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5"/> <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="5"/>
    </g>
    <g fill="#666">
      <circle cx="15" cy="5" r="5"/> <circle cx="5" cy="15" r="5"/>
    </g>
  </pattern>
</svg>

<svg width="30" height="30" viewbox="0 0 30 30">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern)"/>
</svg>

<svg width="60" height="60" viewbox="0 0 60 60">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern)"/>
</svg>

<svg width="90" height="90" viewbox="0 0 90 90">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern)"/>
</svg>
```

> доп. инфа:
>
> 1. `pattern` используется как бесшовная текстура (как `background-repeat: repeat`)
> 2. текстура выглядит следующим образом
>    [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что решение кроется в каком-то танце с бубнами с `patternUnits`, но я уже какие-только варианты не испробовал с ним -_-

Comment: Это похоже на нормальное и ожидаемое поведение от SCALABLE vector graphics. В этом и весь смысл масштабируемости. Неужели если через background-image в CSS задать, то будет так же?

Comment: @Leonid, логичное поведение, но вдруг есть возможность фиксировать паттерн, ну или хотя бы редактировать заливку фигуры этим паттерном.

Comment: Вроде же фактическое решение вопроса есть, если убрать viewBox из мелких SVG, то работает как надо... То есть, нужно решение не обходное, а именно с настройками самого `pattern`? `patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` как раз и настраивает это поведение. Подождем Александра, он что-нибудь придумает, разрулит с высоты своего опыта и знания всех нюансов))

Comment: Я понять не могу, в примере 8 цветов а в патерне 1 ...где подводные камни ?

Answer (score 2):

Любые регулировки позиционирования и масштабирования растрового изображения внутри `pattern`, не смогут на 100% решить проблему возникновения всяческих артефактов при заполнением паттерном объектов. В одном месте подберёте нужные параметры, с другой стороны буквы появятся новые артефакты.

*Нужно также учесть, что происходит двойное масштабирование и позиционирование при вставке растра в svg патерн и при заполнении патерном другого объекта.*

И если даже удастся после долгих мучений подобрать боле-менее подходящий результат на своём  ПК, то с большой долей вероятности на другом ПК будет смотреться всё несколько по другому. Так как у других пользователей могут быть установлены другие шрифты по умолчанию, другое разрешение экрана, другая ОС, другой браузер, другая видеокарта.

**Предлагаю использовать другой подход**

Вместо растровой картинки логотипа с цветными узорами, использовать буквы, как векторные объекты, которые можно заполнить SVG паттерном c цветными прямоугольниками, как на изображении  в примере вопроса.

В первом примере в паттерне размером 100х100px заполняется только одна строка разноцветными 5 квадратами 10 х 10 px. Далее эта строка 10 раз повторяются, поэтому получились цветные столбики.

```css
.letter {

stroke:black;
stroke-width:2;
}

#gr {
fill:url(#myLet);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="-60 0 1000 250" version="1.1" id="svg2" style="border:1px solid;background:#111;"> 
 <defs>
      <pattern id="myLet"
              x="-33" y="19" width="100" height="20"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
             <g stroke="black"> 
               <rect fill="#DF2500" stroke="black" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" /> 
                 <rect fill="#DEFF01" stroke="black" x="20" y="0" width="20" height="20" /> 
                  <rect fill="#03FF59" stroke="black" x="40" y="0" width="20" height="20" /> 
                    <rect fill="#62F7FA" stroke="black" x="60" y="0" width="20" height="20" /> 
                     <rect fill=" #8800FB"  x="80" y="0" width="20" height="20" /> 
            </g>         
      </pattern>  
                 
  </defs>  
  
  <g id="gr"  >
    <path id="D" class="letter"  d="M15 200c37 0 59-29 59-68V88c0-44-23-68-61-68h-43c-2 0-3 1-3 3v174c0 2 1 3 3 3zm11-56c0 7-5 7-7 7l-1-2V69l1-2 5 1 2 6z" />
    <path id="E" class="letter" d="M102 197c0 1 1 3 3 3h86c1 0 2-1 2-3v-44c0-2-1-3-2-3h-42l-1-2v-14l1-2h20l2-2V87l-2-2h-19l-2-2V70l2-2h40c2 0 3-1 3-2V22c0-1-1-2-3-2h-85c-2 0-3 1-3 3z" />
    <path id="dot" class="letter" d="m257 166-2-1h-30l-2 2v30l2 3h29c2 0 3-1 3-3z" />
    <path id="M" class="letter" d="M330 200c1 0 2-1 2-3v-70l1-3c1 0 2 0 3 5l11 68c0 2 1 3 2 3h27c2 0 3-1 3-2l13-74 1-5 1 3v75c0 2 1 3 3 3h43c1 0 3-1 3-3V22c0-1-1-2-3-2h-67l-2 2-6 48-1 2-1-2-7-48-3-2h-64l-2 2v176l2 2z" />
    <path id="I" class="letter" d="m516 200 2-3V22l-2-2h-42l-2 2v174c0 2 2 4 3 4z" />
    <path id="N" class="letter" d="M548 196c0 2 1 4 3 4h36c2 0 3-2 3-3v-43l1-3c1 0 2 1 2 3l11 43c0 2 2 3 3 3h45l2-3V23c0-2-1-3-3-3h-36c-2 0-3 1-3 3v53l-1 4-2-3-14-54c-1-2-2-3-4-3h-40c-2 0-3 1-3 3z" />
    <path id="O" class="letter" d="M682 146c0 37 24 55 50 55 27 0 50-18 50-55V75c0-38-23-56-50-56-26 0-50 18-50 56zm47-71c0-3 1-6 3-6 3 0 4 3 4 6v70c0 3-1 6-4 6-2 0-3-3-3-6z" />
    <path  id="V" class="letter"d="M850 22c0-1-1-2-3-2h-43c-1 0-2 1-1 2l32 175 3 3h47c1 0 3-1 3-3l33-174c0-2 0-3-2-3h-41c-2 0-3 1-3 3l-10 74-1 2-2-2z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Здесь пять строк паттерна, каждая из которых наполнена 5 цв. квадратами.
Внутри  строк квадраты одного цвета смещены, например красный. Так получается необходимая цветная дорожка.

Некоторый выбег части цветного квадрата, вызван тем, что буквы этого шрифта имеют разную ширину.  Необходимо использовать моноширный шрифт.

```css
.container{
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
.letter {
stroke:black;
stroke-width:2;
}

#gr {
fill:url(#myLet);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="-40 -19 1000 250" version="1.1" id="svg2" style="border:1px solid;background:#111;"> 
 <defs>
      <pattern id="myLet"
              x="-33" y="19" width="100" height="100"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
             <g stroke="black" >  
                <!-- 1-строка -->
               <rect fill="#DF2500" stroke="black" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" /> 
                 <rect fill="#DEFF01" stroke="black" x="20" y="0" width="20" height="20" /> 
                  <rect fill="#03FF59" stroke="black" x="40" y="0" width="20" height="20" /> 
                    <rect fill="#62F7FA" stroke="black" x="60" y="0" width="20" height="20" /> 
                     <rect fill=" #8800FB"  x="80" y="0" width="20" height="20" />  
                 <!-- 2-строка -->  
                <rect fill=" #8800FB"  x="0" y="20" width="20" height="20" />  
                 <rect fill="#DF2500"  x="20" y="20" width="20" height="20" /> 
                  <rect fill="#DEFF01"  x="40" y="20" width="20" height="20" /> 
                   <rect fill="#03FF59"  x="60" y="20" width="20" height="20" /> 
                    <rect fill="#62F7FA"  x="80" y="20" width="20" height="20" /> 
                      
                 <!-- 3-строка -->  
                <rect fill="#62F7FA"  x="0" y="40" width="20" height="20" /> 
                <rect fill=" #8800FB"  x="20" y="40" width="20" height="20" />  
                 <rect fill="#DF2500"  x="40" y="40" width="20" height="20" /> 
                  <rect fill="#DEFF01"  x="60" y="40" width="20" height="20" /> 
                   <rect fill="#03FF59"  x="80" y="40" width="20" height="20" /> 
                <!-- 4-строка -->   
             <rect fill="#03FF59"  x="0" y="60" width="20" height="20" />   
              <rect fill="#62F7FA"  x="20" y="60" width="20" height="20" /> 
               <rect fill=" #8800FB" x="40" y="60" width="20" height="20" />  
                <rect fill="#DF2500"  x="60" y="60" width="20" height="20" /> 
                 <rect fill="#DEFF01"  x="80" y="60" width="20" height="20" /> 
                    <!-- 5-строка -->   
            <rect fill="#DEFF01"  x="0" y="80" width="20" height="20" />   
             <rect fill="#03FF59"  x="20" y="80" width="20" height="20" />   
              <rect fill="#62F7FA"  x="40" y="80" width="20" height="20" /> 
               <rect fill=" #8800FB" x="60" y="80" width="20" height="20" />  
                <rect fill="#DF2500"  x="80" y="80" width="20" height="20" /> 
                         
            </g>         
      </pattern>  
                 
  </defs>  
  
  <g id="gr"  >
    <path id="D" class="letter"  d="M15 200c37 0 59-29 59-68V88c0-44-23-68-61-68h-43c-2 0-3 1-3 3v174c0 2 1 3 3 3zm11-56c0 7-5 7-7 7l-1-2V69l1-2 5 1 2 6z" />
    <path id="E" class="letter" d="M102 197c0 1 1 3 3 3h86c1 0 2-1 2-3v-44c0-2-1-3-2-3h-42l-1-2v-14l1-2h20l2-2V87l-2-2h-19l-2-2V70l2-2h40c2 0 3-1 3-2V22c0-1-1-2-3-2h-85c-2 0-3 1-3 3z" />
    <path id="dot" class="letter" d="m257 166-2-1h-30l-2 2v30l2 3h29c2 0 3-1 3-3z" />
    <path id="M" class="letter" d="M330 200c1 0 2-1 2-3v-70l1-3c1 0 2 0 3 5l11 68c0 2 1 3 2 3h27c2 0 3-1 3-2l13-74 1-5 1 3v75c0 2 1 3 3 3h43c1 0 3-1 3-3V22c0-1-1-2-3-2h-67l-2 2-6 48-1 2-1-2-7-48-3-2h-64l-2 2v176l2 2z" />
    <path id="I" class="letter" d="m516 200 2-3V22l-2-2h-42l-2 2v174c0 2 2 4 3 4z" />
    <path id="N" class="letter" d="M548 196c0 2 1 4 3 4h36c2 0 3-2 3-3v-43l1-3c1 0 2 1 2 3l11 43c0 2 2 3 3 3h45l2-3V23c0-2-1-3-3-3h-36c-2 0-3 1-3 3v53l-1 4-2-3-14-54c-1-2-2-3-4-3h-40c-2 0-3 1-3 3z" />
    <path id="O" class="letter" d="M682 146c0 37 24 55 50 55 27 0 50-18 50-55V75c0-38-23-56-50-56-26 0-50 18-50 56zm47-71c0-3 1-6 3-6 3 0 4 3 4 6v70c0 3-1 6-4 6-2 0-3-3-3-6z" />
    <path  id="V" class="letter"d="M850 22c0-1-1-2-3-2h-43c-1 0-2 1-1 2l32 175 3 3h47c1 0 3-1 3-3l33-174c0-2 0-3-2-3h-41c-2 0-3 1-3 3l-10 74-1 2-2-2z" />
  </g>
</svg> 
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Update

2-ой образец лого

```css
.container{
width:100vw;
height:auto;
}
.letter {
stroke:black;
stroke-width:2;
}

#M {
fill:url(#myLet);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   viewBox="-60 0 1000 250" version="1.1" id="svg2" style="border:1px solid;background:#111;"> 
 <defs>
      <pattern id="myLet"
              x="-33" y="19" width="20" height="20"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
             <g stroke="black"> 
               <rect fill="#F02501" stroke="#C22101" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" /> 
                 
            </g>         
      </pattern>  
                 
  </defs>  
  
    <path id="M" class="letter" d="M330 200c1 0 2-1 2-3v-70l1-3c1 0 2 0 3 5l11 68c0 2 1 3 2 3h27c2 0 3-1 3-2l13-74 1-5 1 3v75c0 2 1 3 3 3h43c1 0 3-1 3-3V22c0-1-1-2-3-2h-67l-2 2-6 48-1 2-1-2-7-48-3-2h-64l-2 2v176l2 2z" />
    
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Привет, спасибо. В качестве фигуры используется текст с шрифтом, который переведён в path, в качестве патерна используется текстура золота (как раз растровое изображение). Увы такой вариант не подходит. Похоже придётся подгонять паттерн, эх :с

Comment: @De.Minov Лучше бы давать в вопросе и финальную картинку, что хочешь получить в итоге. В вопросе одно - цветные квадраты рядами по диагонали, а оказывается, что нужна текстура золота.  И в ответе я же написал, что можно подогнать идеально на своем компьютере, но на другом ПК это будет выглядеть по другому. Можно ведь и другие решения поискать, но нужно чётко увидеть, отвечающим, что нужно на самом деле.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, я так понял, что смысл в том, чтобы при масштабировании SVG, и соответственно масштабировании замкнутых путей в нем (уменьшении или увеличении) заливка паттерном не масштабировалась, а как бы раздвигалась видимость бесконечного поля повторяемого узора. А сейчас мы захватываем фигурой определенный участок этого поля и при масштабировании этот участок не меняется.

Comment: @Leonid смысл в том, чтобы дать в вопросе ясное понимание отвечающим, что хочет получить автор в итоге. Нужна финальная картинка, что хочет получить автор на финише. На настоящий момент в объяснениях  в вопросе одно, а в итоге оказывается, что нужны не эти разноцветные растровые квадраты, а растровая картинка текстуры золота. Решения могут быть разные, всё зависит от нужного финального результата.

Comment: Добавленная автором текстура - как настроечная таблица, только для пояснения принципов работы. Это может быть любое растровое изображение. И повторяемость здесь не важна на самом деле. Это могла быть текстура дерева без повторений 3000*3000 пикселей. Прямоугольник размером 30*30 будет отображать 30*30 пикселей этой текстуры, например. При увеличении SVG с настроенным `viewBox` фактически квадратик увеличится в абсолютных значениях, но в относительных единицах SVG останется 30*30. А надо, чтобы при абсолютных 90*90 и текстура захватывалась 90*90 от 3000*3000. Как-то так)))

Comment: @Leonid ну вот и ты попался в сети навязываемого решения. А если это невозможно кроссбраузерно реализовать, реализовать для любых разрешений экрана и гаджетов? Слова понимаются по разному. Я до сих пор  четко не понимаю, что автору нужно. Разве трудно дать четкий финальный результат, с реальной текстурой, с изображением как она заполняет объект. выполненный в любом растровом редакторе.  Чёткое понимание задачи,- это основное условие нахождения нужного решения.

Comment: В том то и дело, что проблема надуманная. Background-image по умолчанию имеет такое поведение. А для SVG я сразу написал, что на то она и SCALABLE, и лично я никакого практического смысла в этом не вижу. Но я также не вижу как background-image из CSS можно применить для фигур SVG. Наверное, можно. Но автор, как я понял, хочет добиться результата непременно настройками свойств паттерна. А вот тут и есть тупик. Если есть такая возможность - отлично, нет - еще лучше))) Реальной мотивации зачем нужно загонять себя в такой тупик автор не предоставил...

Comment: @Leonid совершенно согласен, что в таком виде это тупик. Так как атрибуты паттерна с наружи ни CSS, ни JS невозможно изменить. Мало того, даже покраска его возможна только внутри паттерна.  У меня в голове несколько способов, как можно сделать тот или иной вариант заполнением текстурой, НО, не хочется их предлагать, чтобы получить в ответ,- мне это не подходит. Я ценю своё время, поэтому и автору нужно потратить своё время, чтобы донести однозначное понимание до отвечающих.

Comment: Ясно, особенно это весело когда отвечающему даже плюс за работу не ставится автором. Хорошо, не принимай как правильный, но нос воротить от работы людей, которые помощь свою предлагают...